# How to upload an excel file into sql server using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an excel report like this:

```
      A          B         C          D         E    
1  -------   -------    07/01/14   07/02/14  07/03/14  
2  Location:   Alief  
3  Owner:      01354  
4  Sales:                1,244       2,323      988  
5  Supply:                800         500       200  
6  
7  Location:   Cypress  
8  Owner:      01358  
9  Sales:                5,231       5,323      4,988  
10 Supply:                4000        2800      1500  
11
```

The dates change each week the report its uploaded and there are 50+ locations, owner, ie sets of data in each report(so 1 excel report has 250+ rows).

I need to import this excel file into SQL server 2008 R2 using C#.  After uploading the file, I need to parse each section out and then unpivot each section so they can be stored properly.  All the examples I've seen online show a simple excel file with row 1 as headers and the remaining rows as data.  Any help in the direction I need to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's all the code you need to do what you're talking about. Just edit the connection string and the table information. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/636719/Import-MS-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-table-using-Csh

Comment: Thanks for some direction, I've decided to grab the data into to tables before I sqlbulkcopy upload them.